# Opening Angular 6 links bound by [innerHTML] in a new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 6 app with a `<div>` that gets populated via an `[innerHTML]` binding. How can I apply `target='_blank'` to all the links inside this `div`?

**What I've tried:**

So far, I've tried creating a directive that wraps the div and, after change detection gets run, pulls up a list of child `<a>` tags and applies a `target='_blank'` attribute. So far, I have not been able to get `ContentChildren` to access any of the links: It just pulls up an empty list.

Does anyone have experience doing this, or is there a more elegant solution?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appExternalLink]'
})
export class ExternalLinkDirective implements AfterContentChecked, AfterViewChecked {

  @ContentChildren('a', {descendants: true}) links: QueryList<any>;


  @Input() appExternalLink: string;
  constructor() {
    console.log('HELLO FROM APPEXTERNALLINK');
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    console.log(this.links);
  }

}
```

Then, when binding the content:

```
<div appExternalLink>
  <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us the HTML template for the component you're attaching this to?

Comment: @RyanSearle I added an example of the template!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out I was using the wrong approach trying to use `ContentChildren`.

With the below code, I was able to target *all* `<a>` tags in a div with the `appExternalLink` directive. Posting my solution so other people don't have to figure this out themselves:

```
  import { AfterViewChecked, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
    selector: '[appExternalLink]'
  })
  export class ExternalLinkDirective implements AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
      Array.from(this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a'))
        .forEach((el: any) => {
          el.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! I was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<base>` tag to default the `target` attribute of each anchor.

```
<base target="_blank">
```

You can inject this tag dynamically in `ngOnInit` and remove it in `ngOnDestroy`, but it will change the behaviour of **any** link.

If you want to change the behaviour of just the anchors inside a div, you can use

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.your-div-class a'))
  .forEach(el => el.setAttribute('target', '_blank'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the selector you're using

```
@ContentChildren('a', {descendants: true}) links: QueryList<any>;
```

What this does is look for any *direct* children of the component which have an id of `a`.

If you change your html to look like this:

```
<div appExternalLink>
    <a #a>Link</>
    <a #a>Link</>
</div>
```

Then your selector will find the links.