# I want to embed an anchor tag into innerHTML using Angular, but it doesn't recognize my anchor tag

Tags: angular

First, i googled this. The query "angular innerhtml anchor tag" brings up several threads, linked below, that do not talk about a working solution.

My goal is to embed an anchor tag to several websites into the innerHTML of a paragraph tag. If it can be a routerLink instead of an anchor tag that is fine; I just need the user to see a link, be able to click it and get a redirect, and for the link to come from something I set into `innerHTML` on a p tag.

So far the innerHTML is accepting `<br/>` as html but not `<a href="https://www.google.ca">google.ca</a>` .

My complete input into the **faq.component.html**:

```
<p [innerHTML]="'hey look at this <b>this is bold</b> and this is italic <i>italics!</i> but this link doesnt work <a href="www.google.ca">hey</a>'"></p>
```

I get the error:

```
faq.component.ts(4, 5): Error occurs in the template of component FaqComponent.
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at column 107 in expression ['hey look at this <b>this is bold</b> and this is italic <i>italics!</i> but this link doesnt work <a href=] at column 108 in ['hey look at this <b>this is bold</b> and this is italic <i>italics!</i> but this link doesnt work <a href=] in <folder>
```

This is a reproduction and not verbatim from my code.

I have tried escape characters:

`<a href=\"www.google.ca\">hey</a>` (note the slash `\`)

I also tried starting with double quotes instead of single quotes, and then using single quotes for the href value. but that was a longshot.

Thanks for all viewers and replies

*Unhelpful links:*

[Opening Angular 6 links bound by [innerHTML] in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158674/opening-angular-6-links-bound-by-innerhtml-in-a-new-tab)

[Can't render routerLink in innerHTML in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706767/cant-render-routerlink-in-innerhtml-in-angular)

[How to make anchor link with #id work as expected in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199389/how-to-make-anchor-link-with-id-work-as-expected-in-angular)

[Angular4 routerLink inside innerHTML turned to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613069/angular4-routerlink-inside-innerhtml-turned-to-lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to substitute `""` for `&#34;`

So instead of `"https://www.google.ca"` I wrote `&#34;https://www.google.ca&#34;` and it was interpreted as desired.